# How do I make a VBA function reference a cell on column next to it?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a reference to an adjacent cell of the same row given an if statement.

=CheckColour1(D26)  looks for the background colour of the cell in column D and outputs a statement in column E. (This function is entered in column E).

I want this function to look for the background colour of the cell in column D and if it's orange, output the value in the cell, exactly 4 columns to the right. i.e if =CheckColour1(G2) is used in column D and the cell is orange, value would be coming from H2.

```
Public Function CheckColour1(range)

    If range.Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206) Then
        CheckColour1 = "Good, no CAP" 'If green, keep blank'
    ElseIf range.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) Then
        CheckColour1 = "1"   'If red, write 1'
    ElseIf range.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 156) Then
        CheckColour1 = ""  'If yellow, keep blank'
    ElseIf range.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 153) Then
        CheckColour1 = "Either 1+,2,2+(enter value in col H)" 'If orange, user discretion, type out the value in the row at H'
    ElseIf range.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
        CheckColour1 = "" 'if white, keep blank'
    Else
        CheckColour1 = "Enter number"
    End If

End Function
```

Currently my function outputs a statement depending on the colour only, and doesn't change.

I want to replace this line: CheckColour1 = "Either 1+,2,2+(enter value in col H)" 'If orange, user discretion, type out the value in the row at H'

In reference to the output:
If the cell is orange, I want it to reference the cell in column H (Enter 2+ if orange). Ideally, column H will just have just a number (2+).
[image: []

Comment: `CheckColour1 = Application.Caller.Parent.Range("H" & Application.Caller.Row)`

Comment: Is the cell fill a result of Conditional Formatting?

Comment: Hi Tim, No, I've manually used the good, bad, neutral, input styles.

Comment: Thanks Scott! That was it! Works perfectly, really appreciate it.

Comment: @variatus Column D is a copy of a column from the master spreadsheet, but I found the rules were not copied over i.e. the styles were set to normal.  Is there a way to do that however? At the moment, i'm stuck with analysing the background colour.

Comment: You ought to be able to control what you copy with PasteSpecial. If you make sure to include formats in the copying process you should get everything there is in the Master.

Comment: In addition to the answers being a bad idea,  the whole UDF also suffers from the same problem.   Changing the color of the input cell won't trigger a recalc, so the UDFoutput won't change until you force a recalc.  A better design is to enter a value in the source cell, and base the UDF output on that value.  Use Conditional Formatting to apply the color.  (Another less than ideal but workable option is to make the UDF Volitile)

Answer (score 0):

CheckColour1 = Application.Caller.Parent.Range("H" & Application.Caller.Row)

Answer by: [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner), found above.

Comment: This is a _really_ bad idea.  With this approach the formula result will not update when column H changes. You will have to force a recalc to get it to update

Comment: Any suggestions on how to automate a recalculation?

Comment: Pass the H cell to the UDF as another parameter

Answer (score 0):

Please try this function. I have re-written it for easier reading.

```
Function CheckColour1(Rng As range) As String

    Select Case Rng.Interior.Color
        Case RGB(198, 239, 206)                         ' green
            CheckColour1 = "Good, no CAP"
        Case RGB(255, 199, 206)                         ' pink
            CheckColour1 = "1"
        Case RGB(255, 204, 153)                         ' orange
            CheckColour1 = CStr(Rng.Offset(0, 4).Value)
        Case RGB(255, 235, 156), RGB(255, 255, 255)     ' yellow, white
            CheckColour1 = ""
        Case Else
            CheckColour1 = "Enter number"
    End Select
End Function
```